# How to compare json objects and get particular json object inside json array in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

**JSON ARRAY**

```
[{
    "status": "dummy text",
    "statusId": 3,
    "Imgstatus": "http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/40/6907072-flowers-abstract-backgrounds.jpg"
},
{
    "status": "example text",
    "statusId": 5,
    "Imgstatus": "http://www.wallmuu.com/top/wallfile/flowers-background-high-definition-beautiful.jpg"
},
{
    "status": "sample text",
    "statusId": 4,
    "Imgstatus": "http://www.twitterevolutions.com/bgs/flowers-and-swirls-twitter-background.jpg"
}]
```

How do I get the image urls from `"ImgStatus"` key as per the `"statusId"` key from the above `JsonArray`, and save those each each image URL on a separate `SharedPreference`?

`"ImgStatus"` key contains some image url, and `statusId` is the key contains some id numbers which belongs to the each each corresponding images.

I've tried it here, but its working. Can anyone please help me?

```
SharedPreferences sp = (SharedPreferences)getSharedPreferences("MYPREF",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String statusID = jsonObject1.getString("statusId");
            String imgUrls  = jsonObject1.getString("Imgstatus");

            if (statusID.toString().equals("3")){
                editor.putString("IMG_1", imgUrls);
            }

            if (statusID.toString().equals("4")){
                editor.putString("IMG_2", imgUrls);
            }
            if (statusID.toString().equals("5")){
                editor.putString("IMG_3", imgUrls);
            }

            editor.commit();
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = (SharedPreferences)getSharedPreferences("MYPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String img1 = sharedPreferences.getString("IMG_1", "");
        String img2 = sharedPreferences.getString("IMG_2", "");
        String img3 = sharedPreferences.getString("IMG_3", "");

        Log.d(">> Sharedpref img values  :  ", img1+"\n"+img2+"\n"+img3);
```

Comment: What is not working. You are being very unclear with your query.

Comment: Your String conversions seem really weird to me. Did you try `int statusID = jsonObject1.getInt("statusId");` then `if (statusID == 3)` instead of multiple String conversions?

Comment: Post logcat ,please !

Comment: @Rohit5k2 im trying to show the corresponding images as per the statusId

Comment: Does your log `Log.d(">> Sharedpref img values  :  ", img1+"\n"+img2+"\n"+img3);` print the URL of images ?

Comment: @Rohit5k2, It showing only one image url...what i am trying is, to show the all three image urls

Comment: Then in that case you current question is totally useless. You are showing codes of json parsing and asking about image display. Please update you question or post a new one.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 no no, im not asking to show the images.I need to save all three image urls as a separate separate sharedpreference

Comment: Why would you even want that? How single preference is not doing the job?

Comment: I think he was asking about prefs "fileds" and not entire shared prefs @Rohit5k2

Comment: @Rohit5k2 yeah single sharedpref is enough...here i;ve done with single shared pref only.

Comment: @Fllo when i am printing that share pref, its printing only one image url, not all the three

Comment: But you are already using different fields. `IMG_1`, `IMG_2` and `IMG_3`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 yes, im just splitting, all the three images as a separate fields, that is what im trying to.but it is not coming like that :(

Comment: Small mistake. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 but its still showing only one image url

Comment: Please update your code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting only one value because you have closed the preference in the first iteration of `for` loop. In other iteration no data is being saved.

You need to put

```
editor.commit();
```

outside of the for loop (after the loop).

Comment: but its still showing only one image url